# Is there a special hose to tap connector that doesn't splash?

Tags: sprinkler-system, hoses, water

I have a garden tap inside my conservatory/summer room. The problem is that every time I disconnect the hose from the tap, I get a gush of water that sprays on the wall and floor.
I've tried using a rag wrapped around it but the force is too strong and it sprays through it.
Is there a special type of connector for this type of problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gardena makes hose connectors that have a built-in water stop. I grew up with these in Germany. The orange & grey design is IMHO questionable at best, but they work like a charm.
Afaik they are available in the US, too, see the company's website [here](http://www.gardena.com/ca/en/water-management/hose-connectors/) (scroll down a bit).

Apart from that, it's probably a good idea to switch off the tap and release the pressure on the hose by simply opening the other end - depending on what you have connected, e.g. pushing the trigger on a watering gun or sprayer.

Comment: These are also sold as quick connects and come in breakable plastic or sturdier brass.  Should be available at most hardware or garden centres

Comment: Yup. Click and done. I have fond memories of the summer when my dad (by mistake) installed *one* non-water-stop module when all other hoses had them... Got replaced rather quickly.